# How to export a maven project as RAR or ZIP?

Tags: maven, visual-studio-code, export

I have a maven project and opened in Visual Studio code. I want to save the project in an compressed manner, e.g. as rar/zip. How do I do this? What search term should I use.

Comment: i made a maven project in eclipse.I wanna upload to vscode, and save .rar file to sending.

Comment: Visual Studio Code is an editor. You cannot "upload" something to an editor.

Comment: I reformulated your issue to make it more understandable.

Comment: So you want to compress the result of the build or just the whole project as it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understand the question correctly, here some hints:

1. In order to import a Maven project to Visual-Studio, you may use a plugin, see https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-maven
2. If you build a project, by default, the result is a [JAR-file](https://www.theserverside.com/definition/JAR-file-Java-ARchive) and therefore compressed (Highligthing in the following quote was done by me).

> Java applications and libraries can contain hundreds of different files, including compiled Java source code, a manifest file, XML-based configuration data, JSON-based data files, images, sound clips and even security certificates. A JAR file is simply an aggregation of all of these resources into a *single, compressed file*.

3. If you intend to convert a JAR file to a RAR file, there are dozens of online converters for that, e.g. https://cloudconvert.com/jar-to-rar **Note:** I am not affiliated with them and I have not tested their service, but it offers a nice explanation what the difference between JAR and RAR is.